# Where to put the implementation of saving user specific settings?

Tags: c#, winforms, implementation

I have a grid and when the user closes the form, I want to save some settings for the user who is logged in. I already have the 2 implementation methods, but I am wondering where to implement this functionality:

- Shall I create a static Utility class with the two methods
- Shall I create a new class, and name this one something like UserSettingsManager?

For now I have two methods, but I can imagine that I need more methods in future. What should I do?

Edit:
I see already a few answers (thnx for that), but can you also say why you would go for that option?

Comment: D'oh. Sorry, posted an answer without noticing the "user specific" part. Queued for deletion... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the `UserSettingsManager`, sounds reasonable.

Avoid static classes unless absolutely needed because such classes are less easy to test/mock/inject than normal classes.

Comment: Your last sentence is a bit too general. Static classes are perfectly fine, if they only contain system independent immutable state, or no state at all. Here of course the state is both system dependent and mutable, so avoiding them here is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a second method, as static classes are hard to mock.

Answer (score 0):

As the state required for this functionality is already available in the current Windows Principal object, static class with static functions would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the simplest thing you can think of. If the static utility class uses the least amount of code, go for it.

The app seems simple enough that this should be fine. Sometimes, after coding it a certain way and using the methods a couple of times you'll suddenly find a better spot for it.

If, in the future, you have an additional way of saving settings (say, a different file format or a web service), then you can start thinking about refactoring it. And *always* refactor with the goal of making things simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers folders with correctly setup permissions to store user-specific information.

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` to get the corresponding path.

Encapsulate this in a class like `UserSettingsManager`... in this case avoid `static` since these are system dependent and mutable.

Some references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx